# Get the same index type from array

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to get only one index type from an php array

I have this array :

```
array(
     array 
    (
        "id"=>
        "title"=>"ho"
    ..
    ),
    array 
    (
        "id"=>
        "title"=>"hi"
    ..
),
..
);
```

i would like to get just "title" without foreach.

like :

```
array 
(
    "0"=>"ho"
    "1"=>"hi"
)
```

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For PHP 5.4
Use [**`array_column`**](https://www.php.net/array_column)

```
array_column($arr, 'title');
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use array_map function

```
print_r(array_map(function($element) { return $element['title'];}, $data));
```